How to I prevent my sugar coating from melting on gummy worms
Recipe:

180 Grams of fresh fruit blended
2 Tbsp of Honey
2 Tbsp of Lemon Juice
2 Packs of unflavored
2 gelatin packs (14g total)

Put gelatin powder in lemon juice mix and set for 5 minutes.
Combine honey and blended fruit to low heat until combined.
add gelatin lemon mix until incorporated and cool for 5 minutes.
Put into molds in refrigerator for 1 Hr 30 min
Remove from molds and let sit for 8 hours to 24 hours.
Coat in sugar.
I did all this step by step and they turned out more jello like instead of gummy bear texture and once sugar was added as a coating the coating melted and turned into a pool of sugar water. Sugar used was normal sugar.

Was the liquid in the lemon juice sufficient to dissolve the gelatine or did you add more water there? Too much water from the fruit could also be an issue.

Gelatin tends to break up in high acidic solutions and tropical fruit enzymes (pineapple for example).
Try to bloom gelatin in the water, mix with sugar fruit pure and then add citric acid.
